# laravel set selected option

Tags: laravel, html-select

i have table categories, products, and a pivot table :
[image]

and controllers :

```
public function edit($id)
    {   
        $kategoris = Category::all();
        $select = Product::with('categories')->FindorFail($id);
        $idcat = $select->pluck('id');
        //dd($id);

        return view('vendor.adminlte.admineditproduk')
                ->with('kategoris', $kategoris)
                ->with('select', $select)
                ->with('idcat', $idcat);
    }
```

and select option form :

```
<select class="form-control" name="kat_id[]" multiple>
   @foreach($kategoris as $value)
   <option value="{{ $value->id }}" {{ i dont know what i must throw here == $value->id }}>{{$value->namekat}}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

i dont know how to get option get selected.

when i use this, i got error  :

```
<option value="{{ $value->id }}" {{ $idcat == $value->id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>{{$value->namekat}}</option>
```

> Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted
>   to int

can anyone help me???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `$idcat = $select->pluck('id');` is to get the category ids for the product, if so you'll need to change it to be:

```
$idcat = $select->categories->pluck('id');
```

Then you could do the following for your form:

```
<select class="form-control" name="kat_id[]" multiple>
    @foreach($kategoris as $value)
        <option value="{{ $value->id }}" {{ $idcat->contains($value->id) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
            {{$value->namekat}}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes, thank you, work as intended.

that catagories before pluck really out of my expectation. i should learn laravel collection more.